# TFS Api - Atribuir novo work item a um responsável

Tags: c#, team-foundation-server

Estou criando um novo WorkItem e preciso alterar a pessoa responsável(Field: Assigne To) pelo mesmo. Para criar o WorkItem faço da seguinte maneira:

```
WorkItem workItem = new WorkItem(workItemType)
{    
    State = "A RESOLVER",
    Title = "[TESTE INTEGRAÇÃO] " + solicitacao.numero + " - " + solicitacao.descricao,
    AreaPath = ITERATION_PATH + "\\" + solicitacao.tipo,
    Description = GetDescriptionMessage(solicitacao),
    IterationPath = GetCurrentIterationPath(ITERATION_PATH),
};
workItem.Save();
```

Como faço para ter acesso ao campo **AssignedTo**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui encontrar uma solução, mas creio que devem haver outras maneiras. O campo AssignedTo está dentro da propriedade Fields, então para acessá-la é bem simples:

```
workItem.Fields[CoreField.AssignedTo].Value = value;
```

No entanto não consegui atribuir o valor dentro do construtor

```
//WorkItem workItem = new WorkItem(workItemType)
//{
//    Fields[CoreField.AssignedTo].Value = value
//}
```